# SqlAlchemy converting UTC DateTime to local time before saving

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have the following situation:
 - Postgres backend with a field

```
timestamp without time zone
```

- Right before saving the datetime value, it looks like : 2014-09-29 06:00:00+00:00
- I then load the same row from the db and the value is : 2014-09-29 09:00:00

So in the database the date stored is no longer 6AM .. but 9AM - it's converted in my local timezone.

I don't understand what's happening. Why is the saved date converted to local ?

Thanks.

**Edit**

So after @univerio's reply I tried something: I removed the tzinfo from the date time by doing

```
.replace(tzinfo = None)
```

And now the date is saved correctly - it doesn't adjust it to the local time. I don't quite understand why so I'll leave the question open for now in case someone has an explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Re your edit: it appears that a timestamp with time zone information will get converted to the connection's time zone when stored as `timestamp without time zone` by PostgreSQL. By making your `datetime`s naïve, you are telling PostgreSQL to store the timestamp as-is. This is an okay solution if you are fine with naïve `datetime`s. Personally, I think it's better to avoid these gotchas by always working with aware `datetime`s/`timestamp`s and always using UTC.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What I suspect is happening is that you are storing aware `datetime`s correctly, but are not reading it back with a time zone because the column is `WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Each PostgreSQL connection has an associated time zone that defaults to the system's time zone, so when you retrieve a particular `TIMESTAMP` it gets returned as a naïve `datetime` in the system's time zone. For this reason, I always recommend storing `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` instead.

If you want to change the time zone of the connection in SQLAlchemy to UTC, do the following when you create the engine:

```
engine = create_engine("...", connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"})
```

This should make you read the value back as a naïve `datetime` in UTC.

EDIT: @Peter The documentation does not make it obvious how to do this; I had to read several different docs and connect the dots:

1. the SQLAlchemy documentation about [`connect_args`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.connect_args) that allows you to pass arguments directly to the DBAPI `connect()`
2. the psycopg2 documentation on [`connect`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect), which tells you about the extra parameters you can pass to libpq
3. the libpq documentation on the [`options`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS) parameter that allows you to pass command-line options when connecting with libpq
4. the the PostgreSQL documentation about the [`-c`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-OTHER-METHODS) command-line switch that allows you to modify config settings
5. finally, the PostgreSQL client documentation about the [`timezone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) client setting that you can set

Comment: After a few hours searching for a way to connect using UTC as default I found your solution. Thank you! Very useful. Where did you learn this? I couldn't find it in the SQLAlchemy documentation.

Comment: @Peter My response is too long for a comment; see the edit in my answer.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. However in my project we use engine_from_config method to create engine. I am not sure if I can add connect_args argument also to engine_from_config function? This is not directly explained in documentation.

Comment: @running.t You can do `config["connect_args"] = {"options": "-c timezone=utc"}` before passing the config to `engine_from_config()`.

Comment: Thanks. Lifesaver. Adding flask-sqlalchemy on top of this, one need to set `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {"connect_args": {"options": "-c timezone=utc"}}`.

Answer (score 1):

This was helpful, but while using flask and mysql+pymysql or mysql+mysqldb
only thing that worked

{"connect_args": {"init_command": "SET time_zone = '+00:00'"}}
you can check engine params in appropiate driver connections i.e. site-packages/pymysql/connections.py