# Sqlalchemy, postgres datetime without timezone

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, timezone

I am trying to add timezone support to a python/sqlalchemy script. I have studied timezones and use pytz. I understand I should do as much as possible in UTC and only display local times. Due to the nature of the application, this is very easy.

Everything works, except that when I insert UTC data, it gets somehow converted to local time (BST) before entering the database, and I am completely lost why this happens and how I can avoid it.

My table (postgres) is defined as follows (relevant part only):

```
fpp=> \d foo;
                                     Table "public.foo"
  Column   |            Type             |                              Modifiers                          
-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 x         | integer                     | 
 y         | integer                     | 
 when_utc  | timestamp without time zone |
```

I have debugged sqlalchemy when it does an insert. This is what happens:

```
2016-07-28 17:16:27,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO 
  foo (x, y, "when_utc") VALUES (%(x)s, %(y)s, %(when_utc)s) RETURNING fb_foo.id

2016-07-28 17:16:27,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {
  'when_utc': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 11, 23, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'y': 0, 'x': 0}
```

So it inserts in UTC 11/7/2016 23:00:00. When I query it in command line psql, this is what I find:

```
fpp=> select x,y,when_utc from foo;
 x | y |      when_utc       
---+---+---------------------
 0 | 0 | 2016-07-12 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

What is going on? I am adamant nothing modifies the field in between. It just seems to add the DST hour to my database entry. Why? How can I avoid this?

R

Comment: I found a workaround chaging timezone from GB to UTC in postgresql.conf and recreating the database. It works now but this can't be the only way to avoid forced conversions.

Comment: You can change the timezone of a PostgreSQL connection in SQLAlchemy without changing postgresql.conf. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26106482/341730).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your column type is `timestamp without time zone`, when it should instead be `timestamp with time zone`. This can be achieved in SqlAlchemy with `DateTime(timezone=True)` when declaring the column. Unfortunately the default is False... See the documentation for more information https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem as well. I found the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61068311/4550772) very helpful if you are using sqlalchemy core. But, it wasn't my case as I was using sqlalchemy orm. If you are using orm you might be interested in how I solved it.

I did it by mapping the column like this:

```
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    occurred_on: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```