# Get DateTime fields in UTC from Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get my DateTime values back to code in UTC timezone with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I checked my Postgresql DB timezone

```
> show timezone;
UTC
```

I tried this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106482/169691 (it doesn't work)

```
class PGSQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, info, options):
        options.update({
            'echo': True,
            'connect_args': {
                "options": "-c timezone=utc",
            }
        })
        super(PGSQLAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app, info, options)


db = PGSQLAlchemy()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar problem.

From [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-pass-custom-connect-arguments-to-my-database-api):

> Or for basic string and integer arguments, they can usually be specified in the query string of the URL:
>
> e = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?encoding=utf8")

I urlencoded `connect_args.options` and ended up with

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?options=-c+timezone%3Dutc'.format(
    PG_USER, PG_PASS, PG_HOST, PG_PORT, PG_NAME
)
```

Fixed it for me. Hope this helps.