# sql alchemy connection dont use postgres server timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

FastAPI+SQLALchemy+PostgreSQL

Model:

```
class MyModel(...):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creator_id = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=True)
    created_at = sa.Column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), default=utcnow)
    updated_at = sa.Column(sa.DateTime(timezone=True), default=utcnow, onupdate=utcnow)
```

Table fields in database (PostgreSQL 12):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9SYF.png)

Data saved with timezone.
According to the documentation, the behavior should be as follows: data is stored with the utc timezone, but given in the session in accordance with the session timezone or the server timezone.

When I connect to my database using psql I see quite predictable behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZFV5.png)
This behavior is fine with me.

However, when connecting via sqlalchemy (create_async_engine), I only get data with timezone utc. I do not make any additional settings for the timezone in the connection.

Example:

```
server_timezone = await db.execute("SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');")
logger.info(f"server TZ {server_timezone.scalars().first()}")
value = await db.execute("select created_at from my_table limit 1;")
logger.info(value.scalars().first())
import time
logger.info(f"My TZ {time.tzname}")
```

Response:

```
server TZ Etc/GMT+3
2022-07-26 08:42:49.045520+00:00
My TZ ('+05', '+05')
```

Where to look for the reason? Maybe some environment variable settings?

I try to change PostgreSQL timezone settings. I try to find connection options for sqlalchemy. But this not works for me [SqlAlchemy converting UTC DateTime to local time before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105730/sqlalchemy-converting-utc-datetime-to-local-time-before-saving)

Comment: It works when I use psycopg2, but not works when I use asyncpg

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/481
Unfortunately, this is the normal behavior of the asyncpg async engine. An experiment with connecting with psycopg2 confirmed this.